# How to loop trough radiobuttonlist and if selected show content

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Hi I am having some trouble with my code. I have an ASP radiobuttonlist and want to display contents when there is a item selected. But when I select a radiobutton, and switch back to the old one my content doesn't show up any more.

This is my Asp code full page the javascript in here is commented out so it is not a part of working code.

Before I had ASP radiobuttons I had  buttons did worked as pleased but I had to switch to ASP buttons for a reason.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Menu.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="DomoticaProject.Login" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var radios = document.getElementsById("RadioButtonList1");
        var Login = document.getElementById("lbllogin");
        var Signin = document.getElementById("lblSignup");
        var Reset = document.getElementById("lblReset");
        Login.style.display = 'block';   // show
        Signin.style.display = 'none'; // hide
        Reset.style.display = 'none'; // hide
for(var i = 0; i < radios.Items.Count; i++) {
    radios[i].onclick = function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if (val == 'signin') {
            Login.style.display = 'block';
            Signin.style.display = 'none';
            Reset.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if (val == 'signup') {
            Login.style.display = 'none';
            Signin.style.display = 'block';
            Reset.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if (val == 'reset') {
            Login.style.display = 'none';
            Signin.style.display = 'none';
            Reset.style.display = 'block';
        }    

    }
            }
            });
    </script>
  -->  

<style type="text/css">

.Loginform {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;    
}

.inlog {
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inlog .invoertext {
  display:block;
  color: white;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
  transform: translateY(-34px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.inlog .invoertype {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 200px;
}
.inlog .invoertype:focus {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 400px;
}
.inlog .invoertype:focus + .invoertext {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
}
.inlog .invoertype:valid + .invoertext {
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
}





.Navigatieinlog {
  width: 450px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -185px -225px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45vh;
  display:block;
}

.alleinput[type=radio]{display:none}

.lblnavigatie {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lblnavigatie[for="signin"] { margin-right: 20px; }
.lblnavigatie[for="reset"] { float: right; }
.lblnavigatie[type=radio]:checked + .lblnavigatie { opacity: 1; }



.btn-draw {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 27px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 200ms;
}
.btn-draw:hover, .btn-draw:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333333;
  outline: 0;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.buttonplacement{
      display: block;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}


.Errormsg{
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:14px;
}

</style>


<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

<!-- Inlog -->

<form runat="server">

        <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButtonList55" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedButtonChange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Sign in" Value="signin"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Sign up" Value="signup"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Reset" Value="reset"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <%--        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click1" Text="check" />--%>
    </div>


    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbllogin" visible="true">
                <label id="Login" class="Loginform">

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailinlog" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        class="Errormsg"
                        runat="server"
                        ControlTovalidate="txtemailinlog"
                        ErrorMessage="Email is required"
                        ForeColor="Red"
                        ValidationGroup="Login"
                        Display="Dynamic">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                        class="Errormsg"
                        runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtemailinlog"
                        ErrorMessage="Voer geldig email adress in" 
                        ValidationExpression="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$" 
                        ForeColor="Red"
                        ValidationGroup="Login"
                      Display="Dynamic">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtpasswordlogin" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        class="Errormsg"
                        runat ="server"
                        ControlTovalidate ="txtpasswordlogin"
                       ErrorMessage ="Password is required"
                        ForeColor="Red"
                        ValidationGroup="Login"
                       Display="Dynamic">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Login" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Log in" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>
<!-- Signup -->
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblSignup" visible="false">
                <label id="Naam" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtNaam" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Voornaam"></asp:Label>
                    </label>


                </label>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlTovalidate="txtNaam"
                ErrorMessage="Naam is required"
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtNaam"
                ErrorMessage="Voer geldige voornaam in" 
                ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" 
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </label>


                <label id="Signin" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailsignin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlTovalidate="txtemailsignin"
                ErrorMessage="Email is required"
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtemailsignin"
                ErrorMessage="Voer geldig email adress in" 
                ValidationExpression="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$" 
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <asp:CustomValidator
                id="Signinemailgebuik"
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Email is al in gebruik"
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic"
            ></asp:CustomValidator>


                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtPasswordsignin" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlTovalidate="txtPasswordsignin"
                ErrorMessage="Password is required"
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtPasswordsignin"
                ErrorMessage="Password does not meet requirements"
                ValidationExpression="^.*(?=.{6,})((?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]){1})(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z]){1})((?=.*[A-Z]){1}).*$" 
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Sigin"
                Display="Dynamic">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtpasswordsignrepeat" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Repeat password">
                        </asp:Label>

                    </label>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            class="Errormsg"
            runat="server"
            ControlTovalidate="txtpasswordsignrepeat"
            ErrorMessage="Password is required"
            ValidationGroup="Sigin"
            Display="Dynamic"
            ForeColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:CompareValidator
            class="Errormsg"
            runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtpasswordsignrepeat" 
            ControlToCompare="txtPasswordsignin" 
            Type="String" Operator="Equal" 
            ErrorMessage="Password not the same" 
            ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="Sigin"
            Display="Dynamic">            
        </asp:CompareValidator>

        </label>

                    <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Sigin" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Sign in" OnClick="Unnamed16_Click" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>
    <!-- Reset -->
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblReset" visible="false">
    <label id="Reset" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailreset" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlTovalidate="txtemailreset"
                ErrorMessage="Email is required"
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Reset"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                class="Errormsg"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtemailreset"
                ErrorMessage="Voer geldig email adress in" 
                ValidationExpression="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$" 
                ForeColor="Red"
                ValidationGroup="Reset"
                Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Reset" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
          <!--
            <asp:RadioButton OnCheckedChanged="SelectedButtonChange" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="Radiobtn" Text="Sign in" runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton OnCheckedChanged="SelectedButtonChange" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="Radiobtn" Text="Sign up" runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton OnCheckedChanged="SelectedButtonChange" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButton3" GroupName="Radiobtn" Text="Reset" runat="server" />

  <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButtonList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedButtonChange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sign in" Value="signin"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sign up" Value="signup"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Reset" Value="reset"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
-->



    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

<!-- Navigatie -->

</asp:Content>
```

This is my behind code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace DomoticaProject
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Unnamed16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = CS;

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RegisterUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                string EncryptedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPasswordsignin.Text, "SHA1");

                SqlParameter Naam = new SqlParameter("@Naam", txtNaam.Text);

                SqlParameter Email = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtemailsignin.Text);
                SqlParameter Wachtwoord = new SqlParameter("@Wachtwoord", EncryptedPassword);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(Naam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Email);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Wachtwoord);


                con.Open();
                int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if(ReturnCode == -1)
                    {
                        Signinemailgebuik.IsValid = false;                        
                    }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            }
        }

        protected void SelectedButtonChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButtonList55.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                lbllogin.Visible = false;
                lblSignup.Visible = false;
                lblReset.Visible = false;
                string selected = RadioButtonList55.SelectedItem.Text;
                switch (selected)
                {
                    case "Sign in":
                        lbllogin.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "Sign up":
                        lblSignup.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "Reset":
                        lblReset.Visible = true;
                        break;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is always set each Panel to it's default state before you do the `foreach` loop. Because ViewState will remember the Visible property of each Panel.

```
lbllogin.Visible = true;
lblSignup.Visible = true;
lblReset.Visible = true;

if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "signin")
{

}
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "signup")
{

}
```

Comment: Sadly enough that did not do the job still same problem

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Nope still didn't work altough I did had the same results instead of foreach

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this example

```
protected void SelectedButtonChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        lbllogin.Visible = false;
        lblSignup.Visible = false;
        lblReset.Visible = false;
        string selected = RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Value;
        switch (selected)
        {
            case "signin":
                lbllogin.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "signup":
                lblSignup.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "reset":
                lblReset.Visible = true;
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

and change your List with this in aspx code

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButtonList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedButtonChange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sign in" Value="signin"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sign up" Value="signup"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Reset" Value="reset"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Update**
I have change my code to this.. it is working from mine side, just check. and adjust validation etc message from yours.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Navigatieinlog" ID="RadioButtonList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedButtonChange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Sign in" Value="signin"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Sign up" Value="signup"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Reset" Value="reset"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <%--        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click1" Text="check" />--%>
    </div>

            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbllogin" visible="true">
                <label id="Login" class="Loginform">

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailinlog" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtpasswordlogin" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Login" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Log in" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>
            <!-- Signup -->
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblSignup" visible="false">
                <label id="Naam" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtNaam" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Voornaam"></asp:Label>
                    </label>


                </label>


                <label id="Signin" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailsignin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtPasswordsignin" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtpasswordsignrepeat" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Repeat password">
                        </asp:Label>

                    </label>

                    <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Sigin" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Sign in" OnClick="Unnamed16_Click" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>
            <!-- Reset -->
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblReset" visible="false">
                <label id="Reset" class="Loginform">
                    <label class="inlog">
                        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailreset" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </label>

                    <label class="buttonplacement">
                        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Reset" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
                    </label>
                </label>
            </asp:Label>

</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189628/discussion-on-answer-by-faraz-ahmed-how-to-loop-trough-radiobuttonlist-and-if-se).